# Azure AD auto provisioning

Tags: azure-active-directory, google-workspace

Can you please suggest we can see below error on provisioning audit logs for some users. We sync users via groups scoping from Azure ad to G suite application

Details
details: Skip reason = UnableToResolveReferenceAttributeValue, Active = ?, Assigned = ?, Passed scope filter: ?;

Thanks ..

Comment: Can you share the complete log entry details?

Comment: only this information is available on audit logs , do let me know in case you need specific details -

user.name@test.com' will be skipped. Skip reason: UnableToResolveReferenceAttributeValue